# Why am i unable to insert a data in to data base

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

These are the codes for the page:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['level'])){
if($_SESSION['level'] == 2  ){
require("../db/dbConn.php");


$submitted = isset($_POST['submit']);
if($submitted){
    //check user's input
    if(isset($_POST['issue_type'])){
        $issue_type =$_POST['issue_type'];
    }
    else {
       $issue_type = null;
        echo '<p><font color="red">Please Select a Issue Type</font></p>';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['description'])){
        $description=$_POST['description'];
    }
    else{
        $description = null;
         echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter a description</font>          </p>';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['reported_account_id'])){
    $reported_account_id = $_POST['reported_account_id'];
    }
    else{
        $reported_account_id = null;
        echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter your ID</font></p>';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['DateTimeCreated'])){
        $DateTimeCreated=$_POST['DateTimeCreated'];
    }
     else{
        $DateTimeCreated= null;
        echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the date and time of            the Issue </font></p>';
     }


    //Prepare the Insert Statement
    $stmt = "INSERT INTO problem (issue_id, description,   reported_account_id, DateTimeCreated) VALUES ('$issue_type', '$description','$reported_account_id','$DateTimeCreated')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $stmt);
    $conn->close();
    //TODO 5: Check result of executing insert statement and rows inserted.     Print user's input if 1 row is inserted successfully,
    // else print error message
    if($result==true){
        echo '<p><font color="green">The problem has been created. Thank     you</font></p>';
        echo '<p>Registration Successful Please <a href="../problemTableCompany.php">Click Here</a>';
}     else {
            echo "<p><font color=red><b>Data not saved. Please try again</b></font></p>";
            echo '<p>Inserting Failed Please <a   href="../problemcreateCompany.php">Click Here to Try Again</a>';

    }
    }}
}     else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
?>
```

I am  not able to submit the insert the details from the form page into the database. That is the only issue that i am faced with. Please help me point out the errors that i made.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I do not receive any error from mysql, it just isn't inserting into the database. I think its because, the reported_account_id in the database is an integer however, in the form page we echoed the name of the reported_account_id. Is there anyway to solve this without echoing the reported_account_id? Thanks

Comment: I can't see where $conn is opened.

Comment: This is where the codes for $conn "$conn = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name");"

Answer (score 1):

To Fix the issue, please replace

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO problem (issue_id, description,   reported_account_id, DateTimeCreated) VALUES ('$issue_type', '$description','$reported_account_id','$DateTimeCreated')";
```

With

```
$stmt = "INSERT INTO problem (issue_id, description,   reported_account_id, DateTimeCreated) VALUES ('"+$issue_type+"', '"+$description+"','"+$reported_account_id+"','"+$DateTimeCreated+"')";
```

Comment: I think my problem lies in the reported_account_id because in my database i can only use that but on my website i am echoeing the name of the ID. So i think that is where the issue is .